# Problem using using jsoup in a recursiv threadpool structure

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion, thread-safety, threadpool

The problem I actually have is, that i want to collect data from many urls and because of the fact, that i can only get the next url I have to parse, by parsing the actuall one, and the problem, that because of the response time of the server, it would take way too long if the request weren't sent concurrently, I chose to use a rekursiv FixedThreadPool structure using Jsoup.

But it seems like the more threads are running, the more mistakes the programm makes and i cant find the problem.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MyCallable implements Callable
{
   private final Tree ak;
   private final ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
   private final Node root;
   private long id;

   public MyCallable(Node Root, Tree aka, ThreadPoolExecutor tpe)
   {
       this.ak = aka;
       this.executor = tpe;
       this.root = Root;
   }

   @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception, IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(this.root.getLink()).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        int i = 0;
        for (Element link : links) {
            String adresse = link.attr("abs:href");
            if(adresse.contains("/keyword/"){
                Node neu = this.ak.addifnotexists(link.text(),adresse, this.id ,root , false); 
                if (neu != null){
                    i++;
                    this.executor.submit(new MyCallable(neu,this.ak,this.executor));
                }
            }
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

EDIT: @ akshaya pandey

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;
public class Tree
{
    Vector<Node> allNodes = new Vector<Node> (25000, 1000);
    public synchronized Node addifnotexists(String Kategoriename, String Link, long id, Node Root, boolean first) throws InterruptedException{
        boolean existsalready = false;
        if (!first){
            existsalready = doesexist(Kategoriename, Link);
        }  
        if (!existsalready){
            allNodes.add(new Node(Kategoriename, Link, id, Root, new String[10][101], first));  
        }
        if (existsalready) {
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println(allNodes.size());
        return allNodes.get(allNodes.size()-1);
    }
    private synchronized boolean doesexist (String kategorie, String lilink) { 
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;
        String Kat;
        char[] Kate;
        for (Node node : allNodes){  
            if (node.getKategorie().equals(kategorie)){
                Kat = node.getLink();
                Kate = Kat.toCharArray();
                for (char bstb : Kate){
                    if (bstb == ('/')){
                        i++;
                        if (i == 5){
                            start = j;
                        }
                        if (i == 6){
                            end = j;
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                Kat = Kat.substring(Math.abs(start), Math.abs(end+1));
                Kate = lilink.toCharArray();
                i = 0;
                j = 0;
                for (char bstb : Kate){
                    if (bstb == ('/')){
                        i++;
                        if (i == 5){
                            start = j;
                        }
                        if (i == 6){
                            end = j;
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                String linkvergleich = lilink.substring(Math.abs(start), Math.abs(end+1));
                if(linkvergleich.equals(Kat)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
public class Node implements Serializable
{
    private final Node root;
    private final String kategorie;
    private final String link;
    private final String[][] bestsellerliste;
    private final long ID;
    private ArrayList <Node> naechster = new ArrayList <Node>();
    public Node(String Kategoriename, String Link, long id, Node Root , String[][] Produktliste, boolean erster)
    {
        this.root = Root;
        this.kategorie = Kategoriename;
        this.link = Link;
        this.bestsellerliste = Produktliste;
        if (!erster){
            this.root.setNaechster(this);
        }
        this.ID = id;
        //System.out.println(Kategoriename);
    }
    public synchronized Node getRoot()
    {
        return this.root;
    }
    public synchronized String getKategorie()
    {
        return this.kategorie;
    }
    public synchronized String getLink()
    {
        return this.link;
    }
    public synchronized  String[][] getBestsellerliste()
    {
        return this.bestsellerliste;
    }
    public synchronized void setNaechster(Node next){
        naechster.add(next);
    }
    public synchronized void deleteNaechster(Node next){
        naechster.remove(next);
    }
    public synchronized ArrayList <Node> getNaechster(){
        return this.naechster;
    }
    public synchronized long getID(){
        return this.ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this method  this.ak.addifnotexists (..)   threadsafe ??  Your same instance of Tree aka is being used accross all the threads.

Comment: Your `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` is always executed. Is that expected ? What is the reported mistake ?

Comment: No its not expected haha, just forgot to change it after i changed the whole method @ Kineolyan

Comment: As pointed out by @akshayapandey, your method `addifnotexists` is not thread-safe because you are checking then acting, an approach not working in multi-threading. Also, you still do not tell what is wrong with your program. If the error is that you have duplicated element in your `Tree` at the end, it's something we can work on.